# Using logic symbols "fluently" in mathematics. How can I show that one set of conditions, represented by logic symbols, is independent of another?

Tags: logic, notation, proof-writing, proof-theory

I am attempting to improve my skills in proof-writing. In doing so, many of the mathematical statements that I encounter involve many "sets" of "independent" conditions, which are conventionally represented using logic symbols.

I want to give fair warning to readers: I am a novice to logic and mathematical proof-writing, and as such, some of what follows may seem like gibberish. This is likely due to my stated inexperience. However, I want to assure readers that it is not my intention to waste their time. My goal is to learn to form precise and elegant mathematical statements using the conventional symbolism.

For instance, take the mathematical statement, "Show that the real number is only divisible by 1 and itself". When writing this mathematically, I want to convert the mathematical english precisely into mathematical/logical symbols/notation. However, I want the purely mathematical representation of the statement to be "fluent". This "fluency" depends on the "independence" of sections of the mathematical statements -- represented in english by periods (.) or commas (,).

Show that $\dfrac{n}{k} = c$

*This statement is obviously incomplete; it requires further information, which is usually added using mathematical/logical notation:*

(1) $\forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$

(2) $k = 1 \lor k = n$

Notice this mathematical statement requires two "independent" conditions for it to make sense? When I say independent, I mean that one condition is independent from the other.

And other mathematical statements could have more than $2$ independent conditions.

If we were to simply join these together, we would get something that isn't a fluent, precise, or a correct representation of the mathematical english:

$\dfrac{n}{k} = c \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1 \ k = 1 \lor k = n$

Notice also how the logic symbols "overlap", since there is no equivalent of a period (.) or comma (,). In other words, there is no way to distinguish which sections of the mathematical statement are independent or dependent.

So how do I join the mathematical statement $\dfrac{n}{k} = c$ with the conditions $\forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$ and $k = 1 \lor k = n$? In other words, how do I convert the mathematical english to a fluent and correct representation using mathematical/logical notation?

This is something that has been troubling me for quite a while, and I'm eager to learn the correct way to write these. I hope my question has been able to convey this effectively.

Thank you.

Comment: Quantifiers (usually) must lead and the "conditions" (usually) are antecedent of conditionals : $\forall n \in \mathbb Z \ \forall k \ [(n > 1 \land k|n) \to (k=1 \lor k=n)]$.

Comment: You can see : Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover) (2003) and Benson Mates, [Elementary Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=SjtbngEACAAJ) (1972).

Comment: As well as : Ethan Bloch, [Proofs and Fundamentals : A First Course in Abstract Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=vJLqBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed - 2011).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your gracious recommendations. I am currently studying Daniel Solow's *How to Read and Do Proofs*. As such, I think it is best avoid overlap by studying something that is closer to logic than mathematical proof-writing. Which specific text would you suggest for this purpose?

Comment: You can browse the TOCs with Google... But Bloch is more math than math log.

Comment: "Except when discussing logic, avoid writing the following symbols in your assignment:..."  They then go on to list all quantifiers (universal, existential, etc), the implication symbol, and finish using "etc." to imply all logical notation (pg 6).

They do this to help writers of proofs avoid confusion and unnecessary symbols.  I agree with them, as tempting as it is to try to be succinct by using logical notation.  I highly recommend this book.
Source: "Mathematical Proofs; A Transition to Advanced Mathematics" by Gary Chartrand, Albert D. Polimeni, and Ping Zhang.

Comment: Hi @floorcat, thanks for taking the time to respond. If I am already reading a textbook on mathematical proof-writing, would it be more productive to read a book focused on logic or the one you have recommended? There may be significant over overlap between different mathematical proof-writing textbooks. Also, can you please elaborate on what you said regarding logic symbols? I don't quite appreciate what it is saying (likely due to inexperience). Thank you.

Comment: That depends on more than a few things.  Logic is it's own field.  Of course it intersects math (mathematical logic) but pure logic itself is very different.  A well formed formula in logic (theorem) is a single string of variables (and predicates, in higher orders) that you prove by either contrapositive or with truth tables.  In mathematics, a theorem isn't just a single line of variables and operators, it requires text to explain aspects of it. (1/2)

Comment: If you are interested in formal logic, then I would recommend studying proofs in logic.  There will be overlap (many proof concepts are widely used) but how and when to use a method will probably vary considerably more.  Logic symbols are any symbols used in logic.  $\forall$ or $\land$ $\lor$.  Logic can be highly confusing in terms of convention.  My training used arrows only, so $\land$ is $\uparrow$ for one example.  Avoiding all logic notation in math proofs helps keep your writing clear and understandable, imho. (2/2)

Comment: @floorcat I see. So it is recommended that mathematicians use mathematical english? Although, you often see heavy use of logic symbols in mathematics (set theory). I can't imagine how it would be productive or precise to use mathematical english?

Comment: @ThePointer There is definitely a need for balance.  Set theory has it's own notation (compare Quine to Godel, for example), which does use logical symbols.  That said, it's more useful to phrase mathematical things in mathematical symbols, not English [as you've "pointed" out ;)]   .  On the other hand, if I can say the phrase "for all x, such that" I don't really *need* to use the universal quantifier.  It's very simple to say in English, and very easy to understand.  Does that help?

Comment: @floorcat Indeed. Thank you for your gracious comments.

Comment: My pleasure.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barring formal proof in the study of logic, it is advised to use full sentences as opposed to symbols in good mathematical writing. That is, instead of saying:

$
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
$

> We have
>   $$\forall n,k \in \zz\ \left ( n > 1 \land ( k = 1 \lor k = n ) \to \exists c \in \zz\ \left ( \frac{n}{k} = c \right) \right )
> $$

You would say:

> Consider an arbitrary $n$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n > 1$, and let $k = 1$ or $k = n$ . Show that:
>   $$
> \frac{n}{k} = c
> $$

Unless you need to write in first order logic (for proof checkers or Fitch style derivations), the latter method is orders of magnitude more readable. Good writing involves striking a balance between understandability and brevity/unambiguity. If you want to learn to write good proof in the usual sense, make your writing easier for the reader!

Here are a bunch of resources that will drill this. Every single one of these, in some sense, says what my answer here states: avoid this type of shorthand.

[Source 1](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/math216/mathwriting.pdf)

[Source 2](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/math131/good-math-writing.pdf)

[Source 3](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~orrison/math30b/su-advice.pdf)

[Source 4](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~freiwald/writingguidelines.pdf)

Comment: Actually I would just say "Given any integer $n > 1$, if $k = 1$ or $k = n$ then $\frac{n}{k}$ is an integer."

Comment: @user21820 As would I. But sometimes the set $n$ belongs to may be better written notationally. I tried to keep as  much formal notation as might ever be needed in most scenarios.

Comment: @user21820 Also I did hijack your first order formula, so thank you!

Comment: Ah. If I use set notation to emphasize the membership in it, I would clump the whole thing together as $\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$. But certainly we agree that we can't write "$\forall\ n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$". =)

Answer (score 1):

The right way to write your statement symbolically (according to my guess of what you mean) is:
$
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

> $\forall n,k \in \zz\ \Big( n > 1 \land ( k = 1 \lor k = n ) \to \exists c \in \zz\ \big( \lfrac{n}{k} = c \big) \Big)$

By the way, it is always possible to express any mathematical statement in symbolic form. In fact, for almost all of modern mathematics, if it cannot be done in some fixed format (such as first-order sentence over ZFC) then it is not a mathematical statement! However, as others have pointed out, in mathematical writing we use symbols to facilitate understanding, and not just for the sake of conciseness or precision. Even if the goal is for it to be computer-checkable, it is very uncommon for symbols as opposed to ASCII keywords to be used, because it is difficult to type symbols. For example Coq uses the keyword "forall" and not the symbol "$\forall$".

In my opinion, a clear way to express your statement in writing would be:

> Given any integer $n > 1$, if $k = 1$ or $k = n$ then $\lfrac{n}{k}$ is an integer.

It is barely a little longer than the symbolic form, and yet conveys all the information in an easily readable English sentence. If you want a shorter version you can use more symbols (which would need more prior definitions):

> Given any $n \in \zz_{>1}$, if $k \in \{1,n\}$ then $\lfrac{n}{k} \in \zz$.

It is clearly a trade-off between readability and conciseness. Note that a significant factor is the use of set-theoretic notation, which is commonly used in modern mathematical writing. Also, it is an understood convention to leave out universal quantifiers at the outermost level like for "$k$" here.

Freely using set-theoretic notation with first-order logic, we can write a short but clearly equivalent version of your statement:

> $\forall n,k \in \zz\ \big( n > 1 \land k \in \{1,n\} \to \lfrac{n}{k} \in \zz \big)$.